# How can I simplify this query to remove repeated where clauses?

Tags: mysql

I am creating a report that will have different versions based on information in the where clause. The report must have a sum total of the number of occurrences of "closedReason". My current query has three where clauses that must produce the same result. Surely there must be a better way.

The following query works but seems messy to me, how can I improve this?

Note: I altered some table names and results to obfuscate company data.

```
select 
    rccr.descr as Description, concat(round(count(*) * 100 / t.t, 2),'%') as Percent,count(*) as `Cases`
from sales_case rc 
    join sales_case_closed_reason rccr on rccr.id = rc.closedReason 
    join customer c on c.customer_id = rc.customerId 
    left outer join affiliate_btb_customer abc on abc.affiliate_btb_id = c.affiliate_id 
cross join (
    select count(*) as t 
    from sales_case rc2 
        join customer c2 on c2.customer_id = rc2.customerId 
        left outer join affiliate_btb_customer abc2 on abc2.affiliate_btb_id = c2.affiliate_id 
    where rc2.closedDTS >= DATE(NOW() - interval 365 day)
        and abc2.is_outlet is false
        and rc2.closedReason is not null
        and rc2.closedReason in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,24,25,26,27,28,30,34,35,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44)
) as t
where rc.closedDTS >= DATE(NOW() - interval 365 day)
    and abc.is_outlet is false
    and rc.closedReason is not null
    and rc.closedReason in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,24,25,26,27,28,30,34,35,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44)
group by rc.closedReason 
union 
    select null, 'Total', count(*)
    from sales_case rc3 
        join customer c3 on c3.customer_id = rc3.customerId 
        left outer join affiliate_btb_customer abc3 on abc3.affiliate_btb_id = c3.affiliate_id 
    where rc3.closedDTS >= DATE(NOW() - interval 365 day)
        and abc3.is_outlet is false
        and rc3.closedReason is not null
        and rc3.closedReason in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,24,25,26,27,28,30,34,35,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44)
```

Example result:

| Description | Percent | Cases |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Unique closed Type 1 | 49.47% | 1498 |
| Unique closed Type 2 | 3.20% | 97 |
| Unique closed Type 3 | 0.40% | 12 |
| Unique closed Type 4 | 0.03% | 1 |
| Unique closed Type 5 | 6.47% | 196 |
| Unique closed Type 6 | 0.26% | 8 |
| Unique closed Type 7 | 10.30% | 312 |
| Unique closed Type 8 | 11.66% | 353 |
| Unique closed Type 9 | 0.03% | 1 |
| Unique closed Type 10 | 0.03% | 1 |
| Unique closed Type 11 | 0.59% | 18 |
| Unique closed Type 12 | 0.63% | 19 |
| Unique closed Type 13 | 15.98% | 484 |
| Unique closed Type 14 | 0.23% | 7 |
| Unique closed Type 15 | 0.07% | 2 |
| Unique closed Type 16 | 0.63% | 19 |
|  | Total | 3028 |

Comment: You can use a CTE or view to filter each table down to the rows that match those conditions. Then join those instead of the actual tables.

Comment: You could write client-side code that generates the SQL statement from a unified `WHERE` clause. That way the `WHERE` code is written only once, but automatically repeated where necessary.

Answer (score 0):

In general one solution is rewrite this using a CTE.

A CTE at its simplest will be structured like this:

```
WITH FIRST_CTE (columns) AS (
    -- some query
),
SECOND_CTE (columns) AS (
    -- some query
),
THIRD_CTE (columns) AS (
    -- some query
)
SELECT * 
FROM FIRST_CTE cte1 ...
JOIN SECOND_CTE cte2 ...
JOIN THIRD_CTE cte3...
JOIN OTHER_TABLE ...;
```

So in your case we can imagine something like the following (treat this as pseudo-sql since I'm not really a MySql guy and I have not tested it):

```
with (
    select rc.ClosedReason
    from sales_case rc
    where rc.closedReason in (
       1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,16,17,18,19,20,
        21,22,24,25,26,27,28,30,34,35,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44
    ) as sales_case_closed

select
    rccr.descr as Description, 
    concat(round(count(*) * 100 / t.t, 2),'%') as Percent,
    count(*) as `Cases`
from 
    sales_case_closed rc
    join sales_case_closed_reason rccr 
    on rccr.id = rc.closedReason
    join customer c on c.customer_id = rc.customerId
    left outer join affiliate_btb_customer abc 
    on abc.affiliate_btb_id = c.affiliate_id
    cross join (
        select count(*) as t 
        from sales_case_closed rc2 
            join customer c2 
            on c2.customer_id = rc2.customerId
            left outer join affiliate_btb_customer abc2 
            on abc2.affiliate_btb_id = c2.affiliate_id
        where 
            rc2.closedDTS >= DATE(NOW() - interval 365 day)
            and abc2.is_outlet is false
    ) as t
where 
    rc.closedDTS >= DATE(NOW() - interval 365 day)
    and abc.is_outlet is false
group by rc.closedReason

union
    
select 
    null,
    'Total', 
    count(*)
from 
    sales_case rc3
    join customer c3
    on c3.customer_id = rc3.customerId
    left outer join affiliate_btb_customer abc3 
    on abc3.affiliate_btb_id = c3.affiliate_id
where 
    rc3.closedDTS >= DATE(NOW() - interval 365 day)
    and abc3.is_outlet is false
    and rc3.closedReason is not null
```

Comment: I think this answers my question, thanks!